# hyperledger fabric-ca-client through javascript registering more than one user using the same admin identity

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Everything works fine when I have just `"user1"` who is registered using the following lines of code

```
const secret = await ca.register({ affiliation: 'org1.department1', enrollmentID: 'user1', role: 'client', extra: 'client1'}, adminIdentity);
const enrollment = await ca.enroll({ enrollmentID: 'user1', enrollmentSecret: secret });
const userIdentity = fabric_network_1.X509WalletMixin.createIdentity('Org1MSP', enrollment.certificate, enrollment.key.toBytes());
await wallet.import('user1', userIdentity);
```

When I add one more user `"user2"`, it gets registered. But when I try to discover the channel, while running this below line of code

```
const network = await gateway.getNetwork('mychannel');
```

I get the below error

> [Channel.js]: Channel:mychannel received discovery error:access denied

I have declared 2 users in count in `crypto-config.yaml`, still, I am getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

**crypto-config.yaml** is a thing, your Node.js client another.
This means that users you create with crypto-config yaml and cryptogen tool are not the same thing, you cannot use that certificates to authenticate your SDK.

When you create a new user, certificates for that user are placed inside a wallet folder of your Node.js client.
Check first of all that the folder is present and you have correct certificates.
You are probably releasing wrong certificates from the certificate authority.

Comment: I have certificates alright. These are the contents of the wallet folder and the subfolders.  
bash-4.2# cd wallet
bash-4.2# ls
admin  user1  user2  user3
bash-4.2# cd user2
bash-4.2# ls
9657f2767379679b47e2669f5eb7ad1a407d110b9267d8fdc0f64004c139141d-priv  user2
9657f2767379679b47e2669f5eb7ad1a407d110b9267d8fdc0f64004c139141d-pub
bash-4.2# cd ../user1
bash-4.2# ls
5fb07e114c028c1544c3ef8b3aabc77b69b33888d3bc5025c609b7d00ae9f0b1-priv  user1
5fb07e114c028c1544c3ef8b3aabc77b69b33888d3bc5025c609b7d00ae9f0b1-pub
How to check if these are correct certificates? Why will they be wrong?

Comment: Decode them with a tool like https://www.sslshopper.com/certificate-decoder.html